# Turning View into flashcard

Tags: views, javascript

I am working on a requirement to display a 2 column (question and answer ) view into flashcard .  question should appear on front and on flipping the answer should appear . I am not sure whether such kind of thing can be done with view , If there is any custom module that needs to be written , what should be the approach taken for such requirement.

Thanks for any pointer on this

Pks

Answer (score 0):

Views can render both question and answer. Beyond that you need jQuery and CSS for the hide/show/flip effects.